# How to maintain a grayscale image (1 channel) output in a cmyk layered file that contains a color layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, print-design, cmyk

Thanks in advance for your help!

I have been asked to fix a customer supplied ad targeted for CMYK newsprint. It is a .psd doc.

The printer has asked that the file be supplied with the background image, which is separating as rich black, be created in 100% K as it is offsetting, and will offer better registration, etc.

This would not be a problem except there is a two color build yellow logo mark and type on the file.

When I bring in the background image as a grayscale file and flatten the file, the grayscale background image reverts to separating into cmyk again!

Is there a trick in photoshop to maintain the one channel K background and still have the color logo and type on an upper layer separate as such?

Thanks!
Lisa

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your assets are:

1. CMYK logo
2. Grayscale image

This is what I would do

1. Create an empty CMYK PSD file
2. Copy your grayscale image
3. Open the Channels palette. <kbd>Windows->Channels</kbd>
4. Click on the `Black` channel (the last one) and paste your (previously copied) grayscale image. This pastes it ONLY in the K layer, so it will be rendered with only black ink.
5. Click on the CMYK channel (at the top) to continue working with all 4 channels, as one normally does
6. Continue with your workflow (bring in your CMYK logo, etc)

Comment: There are a few ways to do this (ain't that always the way with Photoshop?), but this is by far the simplest.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson: Alternate answers are always welcomed! It is always great to see how different people solve the same problem : )

Comment: This worked like a charm! You are my hero. :-)
I did have trouble at first when I was not able to paste the grayscale image into the new doc. I changed the background contents to white (previously was transparent) and under advanced, changed color profile to Don't Color Manage This Document. boom! Perfection.
Thanks again!

Comment: :) then don't forget to pay your hero by flagging his answer as "the correct one" :)

Comment: I am looking all over, but don't see a place to make you the super hero of the universe! Where do I make your answer the correct one?

Comment: By clicking the check box under the arrows besides the question and flagging my answer as "accepted". But don't worry about it : ) You got now a PSD to prepare!